# R: arguments imply differing number of rows: 163153, 0

Tags: r

Can anyone help with this? The code below gives this error that I cant solve :( I am trying to load the file into R to do topic modelling but somehow I cant get it to work. A snip of file has been attached. I removed all the blank rows in excel so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :( [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ogte.png)

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

txtpath<-file.path(xx)

review<-read.csv(txtpath, stringsAsFactors = F)
df_title <- data.frame(doc_id=row.names(review),
                       text=review$English.title)
```

After running these, it produces this error :

```
Error in data.frame(doc_id = row.names(review), text = review$English.title) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 163153, 0
```

Comment: Greetings Sam! Please provide a reproducible version of your data here rather than a screenshot so people can help you faster/easier. For example, if you run `dput(review)` and paste the output into your question, people can emulate the errors.

Comment: In the image you posted there is no column named `English.title`.

Comment: hello @ShawnHemelstrand,  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-163153L)) . i think may be causing the error